# how to learn Oracle 11ie for ERP support

Tags: oracle

is there a free version I can install to practice and study? Are there any other good resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To teach yourself you can [download and use any version of Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html).  Check out the details of the [OTN download license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) but the general spirit of OTN licenses is spelled out [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html):

> "Software Downloads
>   Free to download,
>   free to learn, unlimited evaluation
>   time
>
> Developers: All software downloads are
>   free, and most come with a Developer
>   License that allows you to use full
>   versions of the products at no charge
>   while developing and prototyping your
>   applications, or for strictly
>   self-educational purposes."

Licensing really only applies to the development of applications for production.